# Are pug templates allowed in Quasar2/Vue3 app scalffolded with Vite option of Quasar CLI?

Tags: vuejs3, pug, vite, quasar-framework

I am trying to use Pug as template language in the Quasar2/Vue3 scaffolded by the Quasar CLI with the Vite option.

In the IndexPage.vue component, I just changed:

```
<template>
  <q-page class="flex flex-center">
    <b3> Hello from Counters! <\b3>
  </q-page>
</template>
```

with

```
<template lang="pug">
q-page.flex
  b3 Hello from Counters!
</template>
```

and I get what looks like a transpiler pipeline error below.

In order to use Pug in templates must I revert to using webpack to build the Quasar2/Vue3 app?

```
(node:6364) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'pug' Require stack:
- C:\Users\robinadmin\Documents\Teaching\Universal\Counters\Volatile\QuasarPugJs\quasar-pug-js-counters-starter-app\node_modules\@vue\compiler-sfc\dist\compiler-sfc.cjs.js
- C:\Users\robinadmin\Documents\Teaching\Universal\Counters\Volatile\QuasarPugJs\quasar-pug-js-counters-starter-app\node_modules\vue\compiler-sfc\index.js
- C:\Users\robinadmin\Documents\Teaching\Universal\Counters\Volatile\QuasarPugJs\quasar-pug-js-counters-starter-app\node_modules\@vitejs\plugin-vue\dist\index.js
- C:\Users\robinadmin\Documents\Teaching\Universal\Counters\Volatile\QuasarPugJs\quasar-pug-js-counters-starter-app\node_modules\@quasar\app-vite\lib\config-tools.js
- C:\Users\robinadmin\Documents\Teaching\Universal\Counters\Volatile\QuasarPugJs\quasar-pug-js-counters-starter-app\node_modules\@quasar\app-vite\lib\modes\spa\spa-config.js
- C:\Users\robinadmin\Documents\Teaching\Universal\Counters\Volatile\QuasarPugJs\quasar-pug-js-counters-starter-app\node_modules\@quasar\app-vite\lib\modes\spa\spa-devserver.js
- C:\Users\robinadmin\Documents\Teaching\Universal\Counters\Volatile\QuasarPugJs\quasar-pug-js-counters-starter-app\node_modules\@quasar\app-vite\lib\cmd\dev.js
- C:\Users\robinadmin\Documents\Teaching\Universal\Counters\Volatile\QuasarPugJs\quasar-pug-js-counters-starter-app\node_modules\@quasar\app-vite\bin\quasar
- C:\Users\robinadmin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@quasar\cli\bin\quasar
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
-app\node_modules\@vue\compiler-sfc\dist\compiler-sfc.cjs.js:1495:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promisify (C:\Users\robinadmin\Documents\Teaching\Universal\Counters\Volatile\QuasarPugJs\quasar-pug-js-counters-starter-app\node_modules\@vue\compiler-sfc\dist\compiler-sfc.cjs.js:1488:10) at Function.exports.pug.render (C:\Users\robinadmin\Documents\Teaching\Universal\Counters\Volatile\QuasarPugJs\quasar-pug-js-counters-starter-app\node_modules\@vue\compiler-sfc\dist\compiler-sfc.cjs.js:2358:10) at preprocess (C:\Users\robinadmin\Documents\Teaching\Universal\Counters\Volatile\QuasarPugJs\quasar-pug-js-counters-starter-app\node_modules\@vue\compiler-sfc\dist\compiler-sfc.cjs.js:3150:18) (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)(node:6364) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)(node:6364) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from the Quasar Framework Discussion forum.
I wrongly assumed that Pug was installed with Quasar since `lang=pug` is shown as an option in Vue SFC's syntax doc.
But in fact it isn't.
So one needs to do: npm i -D pug or yarn add -D pug.
It worked like a charm!